# AS3/AIR check if TouchPhase.ENDED is over object

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am developing an iOS/Android app that requires slide out panels and touch events. Is it possible to get if a user touches an object but then releases off the object?

```
var touch:Touch = e.getTouch(this);
if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.BEGAN)
{
    trace("Tab toggle begin");
}
if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.ENDED)
{
    //If not over object do something           
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is.

This code should help you. It may be more than you need but it works. :)
Taken from [Adobe website:](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS1ca064e08d7aa93023c59dfc1257b16a3d6-7ffe.html)

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT; 
var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite(); 
mySprite.graphics.beginFill(0x336699); 
mySprite.graphics.drawRect(0,0,40,40); 
addChild(mySprite); 
var myTextField:TextField = new TextField(); 
addChild(myTextField); 
myTextField.width = 200; 
myTextField.height = 20; 
var touchMoveID:int = 0; 

mySprite.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin); 
function onTouchBegin(event:TouchEvent) { 
    if(touchMoveID != 0) { 
        myTextField.text = "already moving. ignoring new touch";     
        return; 
    } 
    touchMoveID = event.touchPointID; 

    myTextField.text = "touch begin" + event.touchPointID; 
    stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, onTouchMove); 
    stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onTouchEnd); 
} 
function onTouchMove(event:TouchEvent) { 
    if(event.touchPointID != touchMoveID) { 
        myTextField.text = "ignoring unrelated touch"; 
        return; 
    } 
    mySprite.x = event.stageX; 
    mySprite.y = event.stageY; 
    myTextField.text = "touch move" + event.touchPointID; 
} 
function onTouchEnd(event:TouchEvent) { 
    if(event.touchPointID != touchMoveID) { 
        myTextField.text = "ignoring unrelated touch end"; 
        return; 
    } 
    touchMoveID = 0; 
    stage.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, onTouchMove); 
    stage.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onTouchEnd); 
    myTextField.text = "touch end" + event.touchPointID; 
}
```

Comment: It worked for me ! i'll Include your answer on my question in SO!!